# 2 disks dual partitioning with Windows7 and Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Hey I was wondering if anyone knew of a good tutorial how to do this?

I have the Windows on installation in the first disk and have a second disk devoted to Ubuntu. Last time I tried to partition I ended up getting a black screen that didn't allow me to boot either OS.

I think I might have made a mistake with the partitioning step of the installer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your question? are you hoping for a magic recovery tool, or are you looking to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

If my assumption is correct you are attempting to install Ubuntu alongside a existing Microsoft installation, and you would like a tutorial to show you how to do so.

The first link is a tutorial showing you step by step how it can be done, including the partitioning where you believe you may have gone wrong :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

The second is less of a tutorial and more of an installation tool for Windows that eases the process of installing Ubuntu alongside an existing Microsoft installation:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

Those links should get you started and assist with getting it right this time ***;)***

Regards,

milo

Answer (score 0):

Actually the instalation alongside Windows, but on the other physical disk does not differ from just dual boot instalation at all. However, You have to be very careful not to overwrite Your existing Windows drive thus Yo have to manually set partitions and drives for Ubuntu.

I have done it this way:

After installing Win7 on one HD I have booted LiveCD version and loked up contents of the disks. After that I could easily recognize which (in general sda or sdb) HD contains Windows. And then just pick the right one to install the grub and Ubuntu.
It is quite nice to install Grub and Ubuntu on the same disk, because when disconnecting it Windows boots automatically like there never was Linux installation.

Regards